# How to import correctly external source codes into own C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, zxing

I have few questions about developing in Eclipse CDT for C++ under Linux.
It would be appended to my project in C++ source code from Zxing, but don't know how to.

I had dragged from file manager folder 'core' with source code in Eclipse project explorer with option 'copy files'. I had appended patches to each folder in the 'core' in to the project propertyes->Settings->General C++->Include folder and in any way get brocked compilation with mistake:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv 
-I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/aztec 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/aztec/decoder 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/common 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/common/detector 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/common/reedsolomon 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/datamatrix 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/datamatrix/decoder 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/datamatrix/detector 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/multi 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/multi/qrcode 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/multi/qrcode/detector 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/qrcode 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/qrcode/decoder 
-I/home/svd/WI/eclipse/Test4/core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.d" -MT"core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.d"
```

`-o "core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.o" "../core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.cpp"
    ../core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.cpp:22:52: fatal error: zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/subdir.mk:33: recipe for target 'core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.o' failed
    make: *** [core/src/zxing/qrcode/detector/AlignmentPattern.o] Error 1`

1) How do correct append any external library into the project?

2) What do I need to fix the mistake?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do: use external library or make it a part of your project?

Comment: I had appended all patches into 'include'. You can look it in the output of make-file: all params with option '-I'. This is parts of my project.